# Cross-platform C code and preventing garbage collection

Tags: c#, delegates, cross-platform

I have a set of C functions that I need to use on an ARM target, in C++ and in C#.  I can successfully wrap up the C into a C++ DLL and then into a C# DLL and use all the C functions I've bound successfully.  However, I have a debug function that I want to be able to print to the C# GUI and the delegate it uses is being garbage collected rather than left in place for the duration.

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' has detected a
>   problem in 'C:\utm\pc\utm_win32_app\bin\Debug\utm_win32_app.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional Information: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of
>   type
>   'utm_dll_wrapper_cs!MessageCodec.MessageCodec_dll+guiPrintToConsoleCallback::
>   Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When
>   passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed
>   application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

Here's the snippet of C code that uses and sets up the callback `mp_guiPrintToConsole`:

```
#ifdef WIN32
static void (* mp_guiPrintToConsole) (const char*) = NULL;

void logMsg (const char * pFormat, ...)
{
    char buffer[MAX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LEN];

    va_list args;
    va_start (args, pFormat);
    vsnprintf (buffer, sizeof (buffer), pFormat, args);
    va_end (args);
#ifdef WIN32
    if (mp_guiPrintToConsole)
    {
        (*mp_guiPrintToConsole) (buffer);
    }
#else
    // Must be on ARM
    printf (buffer);
#endif
}

void  initDll (void (*guiPrintToConsole) (const char *))
{
#ifdef WIN32
    mp_guiPrintToConsole = guiPrintToConsole; 
    // This is the signal to the GUI that we're done with initialisation
    logMsg ("ready.\r\n");
#endif
}
```

Here's the C++ code, built into a DLL along with the C code, that can be called from C# and passes in the function pointer `printToConsole`:

```
void msInitDll (void (*printToConsole) (const char *))
{
    initDll (printToConsole);
}
```

Here's the snippet code from the C# DLL that calls `msInitDll()`, passing in `guiPrintToConsole()`, and defines the delegate `onConsoleTrace`, which I guess is the thing that is disappearing:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer (CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void _msInitDll([MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] guiPrintToConsoleCallback callbackPointer);
public _msInitDll msInitDll;

public delegate void ConsoleTrace(string data);
public event ConsoleTrace onConsoleTrace;

public void guiPrintToConsole(StringBuilder data)
{
    if (onConsoleTrace != null)
    {
        onConsoleTrace (data.ToString ());
    }
}

public void bindDll(string dllLocation)
{
    IntPtr ptrDll = LoadLibrary (dllLocation);

    if (ptrDll == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception (String.Format ("Cannot find {0}", dllLocation));

    //...
    // All the other DLL function bindings are here
    //...

    msInitDll = (_msInitDll)bindItem(ptrDll, "msInitDll", typeof(_msInitDll));
    msInitDll(guiPrintToConsole);
}
```

I've looked at the various answers here and the most promising seemed to be to create a static variable in the C# code:

`static GCHandle gch;`

...and then use that to reference `onConsoleTrace` in the C# `bindDll()` function:

`gch = GCHandle.Alloc(onConsoleTrace);`

However, that doesn't do me any good.  I've tried a few other attempts at declaring things static but nothing seems to get me where I want to be.  Can anyone suggest another approach to fixing the problem?  I have a bug that I need to fix and the lack of any debug is proving quite annoying.

Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following line uses some syntactic sugar:

```
msInitDll(guiPrintToConsole);
```

The full syntax is:

```
msInitDll(new guiPrintToConsoleCallback(guiPrintToConsole));
```

Hopefully now you see why the delegate can get garbage-collected.

One simple workaround:

```
var callback = new guiPrintToConsoleCallback(guiPrintToConsole);
msInitDll(callback);
// ... some other code
GC.KeepAlive(callback);
```

Now the delegate is guaranteed to be alive *up to the `GC.KeepAlive` call*.

But you most probably need the delegate to stay alive for longer. As the error message says, simply keep a reference to it. If you need it for the full C# app lifetime duration, turn the `callback` local to a static field in your class. Static fields are treated as GC roots as their values are always reachable.

Comment: Aaaah!  Now I see.  Short-cuts hiding the underlying truth, which I suppose I should expect from something as [generally] easy to use as C#.  Thanks very much for the solution, I'm now happily debugging. :-)

Comment: These kinds of shortcuts are generally required. IIRC they didn't exist in C# 2, and events were a PITA to use, so much boilerplate code. Nowadays this would be unbearable, with lambdas everywhere. Just imagine: `items.Where(i => i.IsValid)` would become `items.Where(new Func<ItemClass, bool>(i => i.IsValid))`. No way for that :)

Comment: Yes, I see that it makes sense, just less obvious that you're creating something at the time.  I'm afraid I'm an embedded C programmer who still tends to put variable declarations at the top of a function...

Answer (score 1):

And the answer was, in the C# DLL code, add the static variable:

```
public static guiPrintToConsoleCallback debugCallback;
```

...and then, in C# `bindDLL()`, change:

```
msInitDll(guiPrintToConsole);
```

...to

```
debugCallback = new guiPrintToConsoleCallback(guiPrintToConsole);
msInitDll(debugCallback);
```

Simple when you know how.